# JLabel's randomly not showing images on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jlabel

Okay I'm writing a program to just test using JLabels to put a lot of images on a JFrame which was going very well until this very strange bug happens where completely random images on the JFrame just didn't show up, however resizing or moving the Frame off screen and back on again would make them show up. I have no idea what's causing this.

but here's what happens about 90% of the time:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAinc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/soRhc.png

now here's my code:

```
public class JFrameTest extends JFrame{
int maxX=20;
int maxY=20;
int Coords[][];
ImageIcon wallImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Resources/Wall.png"));
ImageIcon floorImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Resources/floor.png"));
ImageIcon voidImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Resources/Void.png"));
JPanel Jpan=new JPanel();


public JFrameTest(){
    Coords = new int[maxY][maxX];
    setTitle("TestFrame");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(1200,800);
    Jpan.setSize(1200, 800);
    add(Jpan);
    Jpan.setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
    for(int i =0; i<Coords.length;i++){
        for(int j =0; j<Coords[i].length; j++){
            if (Coords [i][j] == 0)
                drawWalls(i*64,j*64);
        }
    }
}
public void drawWalls(int x,int y){
    JLabel pic2 = new JLabel();
    pic2.setIcon(wallImage);
    Jpan.add(pic2);
    add(Jpan);
    pic2.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(y,x),pic2.getPreferredSize()));
    pic2.setVisible(true);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

}

does anyone have any idea of what's happening here?

Comment: try to execute `setVisible(true);` at the end of constructing your GUI(after adding all labels) and not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setVisible(true) at the end and there is no point of calling setVisible() on JLabel object. Just use update method at the end

```
Jpan.update();
```

Comment: Who ever downvoted , doesn't have knowledge on swings.

Comment: Ah excellent that works perfectly I shamefully didn't notice the setVisible() inside the drawWalls() Method at all. thanks a bunch.